# Testing phases, where is the smoke testing?

Tags: testing, theory

So I was looking to a book and I dont really understand their classification:

```
Unit tests
Integration tests
Smoke and Sanity tests
System tests
Acceptance tests
```

I thought smoke test would be right after integration one? Also I thought that sanity means quick check of the application when new part is deployed.

Also the question: is this correct or should the smoke and sanity tests be in different order. If so, why?

Comment: Belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I do not think so, this is no way related to development.

Answer (score 1):

Smoke tests should be performed before sanity tests - that is correct. The purpose of smoke tests is just to quickly check whether the SUT is runnable, it's interfaces and main components respond to the users actions. There is no deep insight into the app during these tests.
The sanity tests can be a subset of regression tests. Their main goal is to quickly test logic of the application in compliance with requirements provided. Should be done after each major change in the way some parts of system work. And simply if results are negative there is no point in going through more detailed tests. They should give us the information whether tested parts of system match the requirements and specification.

And now the thing is that sanity tests can be put into the unit test level as well as system test level. You can simply run a few unit tests specificly designed to check only basic of functionality and these can be than called sanity tests. The same applies to system test level. So there is no strict definition of where is the place for sanity tests. I believe you should not take it as granted because every case is different and context of tests and application should be taken into major consideration.

Answer (score 1):

A Smoke Test is a **Quick & Dirty test of the most important features** usually done by someone other than the developer after unit & integration testing to see if there's a point in doing more specific/ rigorous testing.

**Basic test of key features.**

- Only test happy path.
- Major features.

**For Example if you're smoke testing an API**

- Check responses are correct.
- Test login with valid details.
- Test main endpoints.
- Check the correct response is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Smoke Testing is the first & foremost Testing done by any QA personnel. This is done once the unit testing is completed by the developer.

The main agenda to perform Smoke testings is to believe your application can handle the positive flow at the Least. Once this done QA gradually proceeds with the following
1.Functional Testing
2.Link & Download Options
3.UI
4.System Testing 
5.Regression for better results from previous builds.

Happy Testing :)